# Insert a character before the occurrence of a substring within a string

Tags: linux, bash, shell, bioinformatics

Suppose I have a string with the following format:

This string is in a file called `motif.txt`

```
str='ATTCTCGGTGA'
```

Within this string is a substring, with a variable name `sub_str`.

```
sub_str='CGG'
```

How do I make it so that I can insert the character 'A' right before the substring?

```
example_output='ATTCTCAGGTGA'
```

In this case suppose you cannot format the string based on the position of the characters. For instance you're not allowed to just put an A after the 5th index in the string. The string could vary in length and thus this implementation needs to handle strings of various sizes.

```
sed 's/CGG/N&/g' motif.txt
```

Comment: You say you want to insert A before the substring, but your example output puts it into the middle of the substring.  Then your sed command inserts an N rather than an A.

Comment: anyways, for the quesstion in the title -- `${str/$sub_str/A$sub_str}` will do it all in the shell.

Comment: Per @ChrisDodd comment https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/ http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/ http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/

Comment: the first half of the question is dealing with two string variables while the `sed` is dealing with a hardcoded string and a file; which are you trying to work with ... strings or a file?

Comment: if `CGG` occurs more than once in the string (or file), do you want to modify all occurrences or just the 1st occurrence?

Answer (score 1):

> How do I make it so that I can insert the character 'A' right before the substring?

You offered this potential solution.

```
$ echo ATTCTCGGTGA | sed 's/CGG/N&/g'
ATTCTNCGGTGA
```

But alas! It inserts an N. Let's change that to an A.

```
$ echo ATTCTCGGTGA | sed 's/CGG/A&/g'
ATTCTACGGTGA
```

Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to fix your question and do some research.

First, as pointed out elsewhere, you say you want to substitute in an A, but your `sed` uses an N... and you say you want the Adenine "right before" your CGG substring, but your example output tucks in in behind the Cytosine.

Rethink, clarify, edit.

If what you *meant* was what you *showed*, assuming every occurrence of `$str` in the file, then just simplify your logic.

sed 's/ATTCTCGGTGA/ATTCTCAGGTGA/g' motif.txt > new.txt

Check your output, and if you're satisfied, `mv new.txt motif.txt`.

If you're trying to abstract this so that several sequences can be corrected, you should still probably replace the minimum uniquely identifiable sequence with its new version in its entirety, rather than looking for a unique sequence and then scanning it for a subsequence to alter, which is going to be more error prone.